# How to get cookies working with Nuxt Apollo and SSR correctly?

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js, apollo, server-side-rendering, vue-apollo

We've built a framework around Nuxt to get it to work with WordPress really well. We have been pulling our hair out trying to get post previewing working.

A common setup will be a WordPress install running on a domain like `http://api.example.com` and then to have Nuxt running on `http://www.example.com`.  There is a WordPress plugin called WP-Graph-QL that creates a GraphQL endpoint like `http://api.example.com/graphql`, and we wrote a CORS plugin to set the correct CORS headers to work with whatever the frontend origin may be. This is that plugin if you are curious https://github.com/funkhaus/wp-graphql-cors

Our Nuxt Apollo setup is this:

```
export default function() {
    return {
        httpEndpoint: process.env.DEFAULT_ENDPOINT,
        getAuth: () => process.env.BASIC_API_TOKEN || "",
        httpLinkOptions: {
            credentials: "include"
        }
    }
}
```

FYI sometimes the API will be hidden behind a Basic Auth UN/PW (like when on a staging site for example), that is what the getAuth function is doing.

This all seems to work client side, but it fails on SSR for some reason. It seems the cookies don't get sent in the SSR request, but they do in the client side request. Am I missing something super obvious here?

*NOTE: I asked [this question here](https://cmty.app/nuxt/apollo-module/issues/c284) 8 days, but am trying here for more attention*

Comment: Have you ever fixed this  ?

Comment: @peerbolte yes, don't use Nuxt Apollo, it's terrible. We use Nuxt GraphQL Request now and it's great.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply  . I quickly browsed Nuxt GraphQL request, but this does mean you give up Apollo smart queries etc?

Comment: Yes, but the Nuxt Fetch API and a watcher does the same thing. Trust me, Nuxt Apollo sucks you'll be happy to ditch it.